# Azure DevOps Server 2020 - Unable to configure backups

Tags: azure-devops, devops

We are trying to move our backup share to another server, but we are running into validation errors that are preventing us.
I found the same error online a few times, but none of the suggestions work.

Running Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1, we use the Admin console to configure scheduled backups.
At the end of the wizard i get the following validation error

```
[Error  @09:43:49.096] TF400997: SQL Server service is running as svc-sqldbuser@int.domainname.com. Please change this account to an account that can be granted permission on the backup path.
[Info   @09:43:49.096] Completed VerifySqlServiceAccountCanBeGrantedPermission: Error
```

We are running a single domain, all relevant service accounts referenced have full control on the NTFS file share specified and the file share permissions have been set to Everyone Full Control.

The same service account is able to write backups today on the existing file share, which has the same permissions set.

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the TFS Backup tool cannot handle it if the SQL Server has been configured with a username@domaim.name service account.

After changing it to DOMAIN\Username under services, the TFS Backup tool could handle it properly and the backups could be (re)configured